# ECTS credits for US teaching credentials

Tags: united-states, europe, credentials

In the southern United States, one of the general requirements for teaching a given course is to [have 18 semester hours](http://www.sacscoc.org/pdf/081705/faculty%20credentials.pdf) at the graduate level.

I currently have 12 graduate hours in two separate fields. Though it's unlikely I'd ever be asked to teach a course in either, I am curious.  If one were to take courses in Europe, how would the ETCS credits be likely interpreted for such a requirement?  Would the common 2 ECTS = 1 American semester hour conversion be used?

Comment: I dont understand why is this downvoted?

Comment: The linked document says 18 hours in the 'discipline', not 'field'. Are you really saying you've done exactly 12 hours in maths and 12 in English (whatever subjects)?

Comment: @JessicaB Yes, that is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

depending what country in EU ( Usually it is few differences in hours ) 60 points ( credits by US systems ) is equivalent to 25-30 hours per credit ( point ) 
It would be helpful if you can clarify what is 12 graduate hours.

- The rough equivalent of 5 ECTS credits is 2.5 American credits,
- Therefore we advise to transfer credits along this 2:1 ratio.
- Students from universities with an American credits system should verify their school's credit-granting process.
- Transfer of credits is at the discretion of the home institution.

This is something that is usually mentioned across internet. 
However according to this [source](http://www.mastersportal.eu/articles/1110/what-you-need-to-know-about-academic-credit-systems-in-the-us.html) `A standard full-time study load is usually 30 credit hours per year. Typically, in order to graduate with a degree, universities expect students to complete:

120-130 credit hours for a Bachelor’s degree

so 1.67 ECTS = 1.00 US College Credit Hours

`

Comment: By graduate hours I mean US semester hours taken at the graduate (masters or doctoral) level. Most systems I see equate ECTS hours by the rough hours-of-work (and per ECTS documents), but in the US, graduate credit hours generally imply substantially more work than undergraduate hours. That doesn't seem to be the case with ETCS credits, but I'm most interested in how US accreditation agencies might view.

Comment: you should follow a diploma supplement ( or if you were exchange student  a course curriculum list, where activities are explained ) in these documents there are guidelines and explanations for US acc agencies @guifa